# Retornar aniversário de contratação semanalmente em SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso disponibilizar informação dos aniversariantes de contratação por Semana. Exemplificando uma vez por semana o RH irá enviar uma mensagem de felicitações para os aniversariantes de contratação.

Criei a seguinte consulta SQL:

```
SELECT

    HIRE_DATE AS DATA_CONTRATACAO,
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM HIRE_DATE) AS DIA_CONTRATACAO,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM HIRE_DATE) AS MES_CONTRATACAO,
    SYSDATE AS HOJE,
    SYSDATE+7 AS DATA_LIMITE


FROM
    EMPLOYEES

WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM HIRE_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) 
        AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM HIRE_DATE) >= EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE+7)
```

[image: Retorno Consulta]

Existe um erro de lógica pois a somente os dias separados
perdemos a referencia de mês como no bettwen exemplo.

> AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM HIRE_DATE) >= EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE+7)

Comment: Uma possibilidade é utilizar um campo calculado na cláusula WHERE: `WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM HIRE_DATE)*100 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM HIRE_DATE) BETWEEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)*100 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE) AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)*100 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE+7)`, ou ainda utilizar `week` com a função `DATEPART`.

Comment: Qual o motivo da multiplicação por 100 ?

Comment: Criar um campo MêsAno para poder comparar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só mudar a lógica do seu `where`.

Converta a data para o ano atual assim:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DD/MM'),'DD/MM')
```

e depois compare as data utilizando um `between`:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(hire_date,'DD/MM'),'DD/MM') BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE + 7)
```

Veja rodando [aqui](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=06ec56f14b492154b3d1ee805d1aa7a9).